# Detect whether application is quit by the OS because of low RAM

Tags: android, memory-management

In the application I'm building, I need to detect the application quitting if and only if the application has been quit when its in the background because the OS is reclaiming memory.

From my own experimentation, the onDestroy is called on EVERY instance. I've tried checking for isFinishing but I'm not 100% sure which situations this isolates it to.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i("V LIFECYCLE", "onDestroy");
    if (!isFinishing())
    {
        // are we here because the OS shut it down because of low memory?
        ApplicationPreferences pref = new ApplicationPreferences(this);
        // set persistant flag so we know next time that the user
        // initiated the kill either by a direct kill or device restart.
        pref.setThePersistantFlag(true);
        Log.i("DEBUG", "onDestroy - ensuring that the next launch will result in a log out..");
    }
}
```

Can anyone shed light on my issue here? Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through trial and error I have worked out a solution that works perfectly for anyone thats interested. I have narrowed down the case when the application state is being resumed (onResume) in the case of the OS reclaiming memory.

```
public boolean wasJustCollectedByTheOS = false; 

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    // this flag will only be present as long as the task isn't physically killed
    // and/or the phone is not restarted.
    savedInstanceState.putLong("semiPersistantFlag", 2L);
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    long semiPersistantFlag = savedInstanceState.getLong("semiPersistantFlag");
    if (semiPersistantFlag == 2L)
    {
        savedInstanceState.putLong("semiPersistantFlag", 0L);
        this.wasJustCollectedByTheOS = true;   
    }
}

// this gets called immediately after onRestoreInstanceState
@Override
public void onResume() {
    if (this.wasJustCollectedByTheOS){
        this.wasJustCollectedByTheOS = false;
        // here is the case when the resume is after an OS memory collection    
    }
}
```

Comment: It did not work for me. I just rotated my phone and the above code told that it was because of OS memory collection.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether its help you or not,

From [Android Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) class,

```
public void onLowMemory ()
```

This is called when the overall system is running low on memory, and would like actively running process to try to tighten their belt. While the exact point at which this will be called is not defined, generally it will happen around the time all background process have been killed, that is before reaching the point of killing processes hosting service and foreground UI that we would like to avoid killing.

Applications that want to be nice can implement this method to release any caches or other unnecessary resources they may be holding on to. The system will perform a gc for you after returning from this method.

And **Since: API Level 14**

```
public abstract void onTrimMemory (int level)
```

Called when the operating system has determined that it is a good time for a process to trim unneeded memory from its process. This will happen for example when it goes in the background and there is not enough memory to keep as many background processes running as desired. You should never compare to exact values of the level, since new intermediate values may be added -- you will typically want to compare if the value is greater or equal to a level you are interested in.

Comment: I tried it and onLowMemory() is not called unless the application is in the foreground. I need to capture when the OS is shutting down the device because of low memory. OnTrimMemory sounds promising but its only 4.0 and above and we need to support 2.2 devices and beyond. Could you maybe shed a bit of light on the isFinishing() and onDestroy() methods? Is there a combination of the 2 that can detect the OS shutting it down for lack of memory? Maybe a way to check that the OS is in low memory state when onDestroy is called?

Comment: I've rephrased my question to make it easier to understand.

Comment: I worked it out. Thanks for your answer though - if only that onTrimMemory(level) was there in older apis!