# Autorestart after OS kills application

Tags: android

friends!

Could you give me example of using AlarmManager (BroadcastReciever, Service) to check is my application killed by OS or no, and if it was killed - how to restart it?

Our customer asks about that functionality.

I asked about that before on stackoverflow, and one guy tell me AlarmManager can helps.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The main concept is **How to detect your application is killed by OS?**

Comment: Yes, and if it happens - restart it again.

Comment: I think this question is suited for (ask to) an Android Framework Engineer who share the information about Android OS role on killing Application.

Comment: There is a method called  [`onLowMemory ()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onLowMemory%28%29) from Activity class, but its not look promising for achieving the task you want.

Comment: Same subject question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11624842/detect-whether-application-is-quit-by-the-os-because-of-low-ram/11625090#11625090

Comment: Yes, i see. But what about AlarmManager that will check, f.e. every 10 minutes is my app running, and if not - launch it?

Comment: I don't think this is nice idea,because What about if user don't want to start your application when user itself close your application?

Comment: Yes, i know, but it is speciall app for one of our customer.

Comment: Then you can..! Implement as a Temporary Solutions..!

Comment: Looking for an alarm which survives reboots? http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html